# How to cancel 'waiting for upload'?

Tags: app-store-connect

I know this isn't a programming question, but I wonder if someone could quickly help me.
I've discovered a minor issue with an app that is 'waiting for upload' in iTunes Connect.
How can I cancel this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Answer is to upload the binary, and then cancel it.