# How to revert "Waiting for Upload" status

Tags: ios7, admob, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload my app to iTunesconnect. It asked me if my app used IDFA and I said "No". When i tried to validate my submission through Xcode organizer, it says that my app uses IDFA. 
I am using Google AdMob SDK to display ads.

Now I want to submit my app, how can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer: [How to cancel 'waiting for upload'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003385/how-to-cancel-waiting-for-upload) you should upload a binary and then reject it.

You could just create a new "Hello World" project and then submit it to Apple.
Once you submit it, you'll find there is a button in iTunes Connect "Reject this Binary".

Specifically, these are the steps:

- go to iTunesConnect
- Manage your apps
- Select your app
- Click on "View Details"
- Click on "Binary details"
- Click on "Reject this binary"